# Facebook not letting me add phone number, says it's invalid

Tags: facebook, phone-number

I am trying to add my work phone number to Facebook. It asks me to enter a phone number after I log in but it keeps saying that the number I've entered is invalid.
[image: screen shot of Facebook message]

I'm using an IP phone but the area code is in Canada (which I selected).

Comment: Have you selected proper country/carrier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a VOIP provider phone number? Some services reject those numbers. Craigslist will not accept Google voice numbers (VOIP).

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure, it is an IP phone, is that the same thing?

Comment: Yes, IP = Voice over IP.